# Function, which outputs the sum of the digits of an integer in C++?

Tags: c++, sum, digits

I have written a function that ought  to print the sum of all digits of a given integer. However the program outputs incorrect result, it should output 19. I want to ask why this happens? The program outputs 2686935.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
vector <int> a;
int sumDigits(int n)
{
    int tmp;
    if((n>1 && n<9) || n==1 || n==9)
    {
        tmp=n;
        return tmp;
    }
    while(n>9)
    {

        a.push_back(n%10);
        n/=10;
        if((n>1 && n<9) || n==1 || n==9)
        {
            a.push_back(n);
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<a.size(); i++)
    {

        tmp+=a[i];

    }
    return tmp;
}
int main()
{
    cout<<sumDigits(12745);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show the the expected output, the actual output, and your debugging attempts.

Comment: And it would probably be significantly easier to turn the number into a String, then turn each character of the string back into a integer. That'll likely be much slower though.

Comment: You know in C++ there are also `>=` and `<=` operators

Comment: what is the output you get?

Comment: You don't have to store the digits into a vector, you can sum them directly.

Comment: OT: Why is a a global variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's way too complex. This should work (except for negative numbers)

```
int sumDigits(int n)
{
    int total = 0;
    while (n > 0)
    {
        total += n%10;
        n /= 10;
    }
    return total;
}
```

Combination of n%10 and n/10 in a loop gives you each digit in the number, then just add them up.

The error in your original code is that `tmp` is not initialised to zero.

Answer (score 1):

```
int tmp = 0;
```

remember that inside a function, tmp will not be initialized by default!

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to init sum to 0 (sum = 0;)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int sumDigits(int n)
{
    int tmp = 0;
    while(n>0) {
        tmp+=n%10;
        n/=10;
    }
    return tmp;
}

int main()
{
    cout<<sumDigits(12745);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation of `sumDigits` doesn't initialize `tmp` if `n>9`, which fits exactly the case covered by your example. Therefore, `tmp+=a[i]` keeps on adding stuff to an integer filled with garbage.

Answer (score 0):

You must set the tmp variable as 0
Here is your corrected code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
vector <int> a;
int sumDigits(int n)
{
    int tmp=0;

    if((n>1 && n<9) || n==1 || n==9)
    {
        tmp=n;
        return tmp;
    }
    while(n>9)
    {

        a.push_back(n%10);
        n/=10;
        if((n>1 && n<9) || n==1 || n==9)
        {
            a.push_back(n);
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<a.size(); i++)
    {

        tmp+=a[i];

    }
    return tmp;
}
int main()
{
    cout<<sumDigits(12745);
    return 0;
}
```